# Storing Stripe Recurring Payment information in Database

Tags: stripe-payments

I am new to stripe payment gateway and I have created a stripe account where I have my plans and subscriptions. It is working fine. Below are my plans and subscriptions in image format.

My Stripe subscription plan
[image]

My Stripe Subscriptions
[image]

Below is my checkout page

```
<form action="charge.php" method="POST">
<script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_ZCRfEl8XeRIbPHGIifY3THYC"
    data-amount="999"
    data-name="Demo Site"
    data-description="Widget"
    data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
    data-locale="auto">
</script>
```

I want to insert customer info like amount of transaction, customer id etc.., into my database when recurring payment occurs in stripe method. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [webhook](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) to get the data when recurring payment happen.

1. Create an endpoint in your application to parse the webhook data and store as you want
2. Add the created endpoint to your stripe dashboard's webhook to indicate Stripe to request on the endpoint.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have used webhook and get the data when recurring payment happen. But I want to do the same thing without using webhook. Can you please help me in this regards?

Comment: I am bit confused now! Let me know for which situation you want to do that?

Comment: I want to insert customer info like amount of transaction, customer id etc.., into my database when recurring payment occurs in stripe without using webhook method

Comment: You can get events using stripe API by time range. By pulling events you can get all successful transactions where you can all info

Answer (score 0):

You can do with `$customer` varibale after successful Payment .you can Collect whole information about payment by `$customer`  If you want to access the collecting card and recurring information after successful payment, you'd need to do

```
$StripeId = $customer['id'];    
$card = $customer->sources->data[0];
$Stripe_City = $card->address_city;
$Stripe_Country = $card->address_country;
$Stripe_Address = $card->address_line1;
$Stripe_State = $card->address_state;
$Stripe_Zip = $card->address_zip;
$Stripe_card = $card->last4;
$Stripe_Brand = $card->brand;
```

for storing information about customer you need to add this on process:

```
$customer = Stripe_Customer::create(array(
'email' => $_SESSION['userEmail'],
'card' => $_POST['stripeToken'],
'plan' => $plan_id,
 ));`
```

stripe also provide you information about payment, see all object by `print_r($customer)`.A `$customer` can have more than one source at the same time. The source property on the Customer is a list as documented [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api#customer_object-sources).